# Convergence of Sequence of Solutions to Elliptic Equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations

Consider the standard uniformly elliptic equation on a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$:

$$
\mathrm{div}(A(x)\nabla u) = f
$$
for $u \in H^{1}(\Omega)$ , $f\in H^{1} (\Omega)$, $a_{ij}(x)$ measurable functions, and the solution being in the sense of distributions. Show that if we have a sequence $u_n,A_n, f_n$ such that:
$$
\mathrm{div}(A_n(x)\nabla u_n) = f_n
$$
and:

1. $a_{ij}^n(x) \to a_{ij}(x)$ pointwise a.e.
2. $u_n \to u$ in $H^{1}$
3. $f_n \to f $ in $H^{-1}$

Then in the limit we have:
$$
\mathrm{div}(A(x)\nabla u) = f
$$
with all the above being in the sense of distributions of course.

Does anyone have any ideas? The right hand side should definitely converge to $f$ thanks to the strong convergence of $f$, but i am unsure on how one should handle the matrix terms.

Comment: We can use Holder inequality.

Comment: @Revzora would you mind explaining slightly more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that $\Omega$ is a bounded open set and the costants $\Lambda$ not depends by $n$, that is
$$
a^{ij}_n\le \Lambda \qquad \forall n
$$
Then thesis it follows by
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_\Omega (a^{ij}_n\partial_ju_n-a^{ij}\partial_ju)&= \int_\Omega (a^{ij}_n\partial_ju_n-a^{ij}_n\partial_ju) +\int_\Omega (a^{ij}_n\partial_ju-a^{ij}\partial_ju)\\ 
& =\int_\Omega a^{ij}_n(\partial_ju_n-\partial_ju) + \int_\Omega (a^{ij}_n-a^{ij})\partial_ju \\
&\le \Lambda||\partial_ju_n-\partial_ju||_{L^1}+ ||\partial_ju||_{L^2}||a^{ij}_n-a^{ij}||_{L^2}\to_{n\to\infty}0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
by hypothesis and by dominated convergence theorem.